# Touch Input system not working on my project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

Hello i'm trying to make my own tetris game on my android phone. I am trying to do,

1- Touch and release screen making rotation,

2- Touching and swiping for down, left and right not making any rotation.

Here is my code, any suggestion would be great, thank you so much!

```
private Vector2 touchStartPos;
private bool isRotating = false;
private float swipeThreshold = 75.0f;

private void Update()
{
    this.board.Clear(this);

    this.lockTime += Time.deltaTime;

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            touchStartPos = touch.position;
            isRotating = false;
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            if (!isRotating)
            {
                float swipeDistance = touch.position.x - touchStartPos.x;
                float verticalDistance = touch.position.y - touchStartPos.y;

                if (Mathf.Abs(swipeDistance) > Mathf.Abs(verticalDistance))
                {
                    if (Mathf.Abs(swipeDistance) > swipeThreshold)
                    {
                        if (swipeDistance > 0)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("Movement for right.");
                            Move(Vector2Int.right);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Debug.Log("Movement for left.");
                            Move(Vector2Int.left);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (verticalDistance < -swipeThreshold)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Movement for down.");
                    Move(Vector2Int.down);                      
                }
            }
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if (!isRotating)
            {
                isRotating = true;
                Debug.Log("Touch detected, processing.");
               
                Rotate(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried many solutions on the internet but I could not find a solution.

Comment: So you say you are trying and that something is `not working` .. but what exactly does that mean? At which point exactly does the code behave different to what you expected?

Comment: for those of us not on a touch computer, why dont you tell us what should happen, what doesnt happen and what you found so far while debugging it